# Why commands are printed from middle of the page in thermal printer

Tags: php, printing, webclient, thermal-printer, receipt

Why the commands in thermal printer start printing from the middle of the page and why it was cut before the first receipt finished. Following is my code ( I am using https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-print-raw-ESC-POS-commands-from-PHP-directly-to-the-client-printer/ )

```
    //Create ESC/POS commands for sample receipt
$esc = '0x1B'; //ESC byte in hex notation
$newLine = '0x0A'; //LF byte in hex notation

$cmds = '';
$cmds = $esc . "@"; //Initializes the printer (ESC @)

$cmds .= $esc . '!' . '0x38'; //Emphasized + Double-height + Double-width mode selected (ESC ! (8 + 16 + 32)) 56 dec => 38 hex
$cmds .= 'ALGERIE TELECOM'; //text to print
$cmds .= $newLine . $newLine;
$cmds .= $esc . '!' . '0x00'; //Character font A selected (ESC ! 0)
$cmds .= 'Serial           1234567890';
$cmds .= $newLine;
$cmds .= 'PIN              12345566778';
$cmds .= $newLine . $newLine;
$cmds .= 'Face Value        129080981283';
$cmds .= $newLine;
$cmds .= 'Voucher Type      Broadband';
$cmds .= $newLine;
$cmds .= 'Mobile            Mobile';
$cmds .= $newLine . $newLine;
$cmds .= $esc . '!' . '0x18'; //Emphasized + Double-height mode selected (ESC ! (16 + 8)) 24 dec => 18 hex
$cmds .= '# ALGERIE TELECOM';
$cmds .= $esc . '!' . '0x00'; //Character font A selected (ESC ! 0)
$cmds .= $newLine . $newLine;
$cmds .= '09/29/22  19:53:17';

$cmds .= $newLine;
$cmds .= '0x1D0x560x00';
$cmds .= $newLine;

$cmds .= $esc . '!' . '0x38'; //Emphasized + Double-height + Double-width mode selected (ESC ! (8 + 16 + 32)) 56 dec => 38 hex
$cmds .= 'ALGERIE TELECOM'; //text to print
$cmds .= $newLine . $newLine;
$cmds .= $esc . '!' . '0x00'; //Character font A selected (ESC ! 0)
$cmds .= 'Serial            0987654321';
$cmds .= $newLine;
$cmds .= 'PIN               28409328385';
$cmds .= $newLine . $newLine;
$cmds .= 'Face Value        129080981283';
$cmds .= $newLine;
$cmds .= 'Voucher Type      Broadband2';
$cmds .= $newLine;
$cmds .= 'Mobile            Mobile2';
$cmds .= $newLine . $newLine;
$cmds .= $esc . '!' . '0x18'; //Emphasized + Double-height mode selected (ESC ! (16 + 8)) 24 dec => 18 hex
$cmds .= '# ALGERIE TELECOM';
$cmds .= $esc . '!' . '0x00'; //Character font A selected (ESC ! 0)
$cmds .= $newLine . $newLine;
$cmds .= '09/29/22  19:53:17
```

[Receipts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DvBu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the distance between the print head and paper cutter.

```
$cmds .= '0x1D0x560x00';
```

Function A on this page is what you are using in your question article.
[GS V](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=87)

> Select cut mode and cut paper

> ```
> <Function A>           Executes paper cut  
>    ASCII   GS  V  m  
>    Hex     1D 56  m  
>                   m : 0 Full cut
> ```

With this command, the paper is cut at the paper position when the printer receives the command.

---

Function B is the one you should specify.

> ```
> <Function B>           Feeds paper to [cutting position + (n × vertical motion unit)] and executes paper cut  
>    ASCII   GS  V  m  n  
>    Hex     1D 56  m  n  
>                   m : 65(0x41) Full cut  
>                   n : Feeds paper (n × vertical motion unit)
> ```

Adjust the paper feed amount `XX` so that the paper is cut at the correct position.

```
$cmds .= '0x1D0x560x410xXX';
```